# Unitinialized constant. Integrating Google API in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-api

I am having a trouble integrating Google API client into my Rails app. I am fairly new to Rails.

I have included this in my Gemfile

```
gem 'google-api-client'
```

Then I have ran `bundle` in my console, in project directory

Lastly, I have created a controller, defined a route, and added

```
client = Google::APIClient.new(:key => "MyApiKey", :authorization => nil)
```

to my controller (I intend to use this with a public API key).

And when I try it in the browser, I get this:

```
uninitialized constant MyController::Google
```

Object creation without params creates same result. I have searched for a solution and tried to add `require 'google/api_client'` to my `boot.rb`, but it made no difference.

Could anyone tell me how I should approach this?

Comment: Post your controller code. I guess you have to include that in controller like `require 'google-api-client'`

Comment: Found a solution. Actually, you reminded me that there were another solution which I have found earlier, so I combined them together.
First, in Gemfile, do this `gem 'google-api-client', :require => 'google/api_client'`
Then, according to that new 'require name', I have added it to `boot.rb` like so `require 'google/api_client'`

Comment: Glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 1):

As per the [official documentation](https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client) you need to require the classes you are going to use, e.g.:

```
require 'google/api_client'
require 'google/api_client/client_secrets'
require 'google/api_client/auth/installed_app'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be adding this line to your controller

```
require 'google/api_client'
```

It should resolve the error.